# What do these momenta mean?

Tags: general-relativity, photons, angular-momentum, momentum, vectors

I'm studying the motion of photons near a Schwarzschild black hole.

My coordinates to describe the position of a photon are $~r$, $~\theta$, $~\phi$ and $~\textrm{p}_\textrm{r}$, $~\textrm{p}_\textrm{$\theta$}$, $~\textrm{p}_\textrm{$\phi$}$.

I understood that if $~\dot{\textrm{p}_\textrm{$\theta$}} = 0~$ and $~\dot{\theta} = 0~$ is, then the angle $~\theta~$ will stay the same and the photon will stay confined within the plane, right?

However I'm not sure I understood what the (angular-)momenta really represent and what influence on the system they have.

Does anyone have a simple definition and example?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: They are probably the components of the four-momentum of the trajectory of the photon in the Schwarzchild coordinate system. The dot is probably the derivative with respect to some affine parameter along the trajectory. (In general though, it is good to answer notation questions like this yourself by reading earlier in the source that presents them!)

Comment: @octonion I don't have any question about the notation, I wanted to have a simple definition, that is: what influence on the trajectory these momenta have. however thanks for answering

Comment: Well the notation matters because it is not clear from your question what the $p$ actually are. That's why I think you didn't get the answer you wanted right away. If they are indeed four-momentum components then they are not quite the same thing as angular momentum. What corresponds to angular momentum would be these four-momentum components dotted with a Killing vector.